# drupal 8 get taxonomy term value in node

Tags: drupal-8

Drupal\node\Entity\Node Object
(
    [in_preview] => 
    [values:protected] => Array
        (
            [vid] => Array
                (
                    [x-default] => 1
                )

```
        [langcode] => Array
            (
                [x-default] => en
            )

        [field_destination] => Array
            (
                [x-default] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => Array
                            (
                                [target_id] => 2
                            )

                    )

            )
```

Not able to get field_destination value directly. It's a taxonomy term attached with the content type. Any help appriciated.

Answer (score 17):

To build on [VJamie's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37134209/102616) answer.

You will need to either set a use statement at the top of your script;

```
use Drupal\taxonomy\Entity\Term;
```

Or, prefix the class instance with the namespace;

```
$term = \Drupal\taxonomy\Entity\Term::load($node->get('field_destination')->target_id);
```

That will get rid of the fatals.

Answer (score 14):

You can also use some methods from EntityReferenceFieldItemList:
Gets the entities referenced by this field, preserving field item deltas:

```
$node->get('field_destination')->referencedEntities();
```

Hope it will be useful for you

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, `$node->get('field_destination')->getEntity();` will simply return `$node` itself. The `referencedEntities()` method is very useful though.

Comment: @marcvangend is correct, [getEntity()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Field%21FieldItemList.php/function/FieldItemList%3A%3AgetEntity/8.4.x) returns the field parent, i.e. its Node. [referencedEntities()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Field%21EntityReferenceFieldItemList.php/function/EntityReferenceFieldItemList%3A%3AreferencedEntities/8.4.x) is the correct answer.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answers. I will remove getEntity() from my answer to avoid confusion.

Comment: A highly accurate answer

Comment: This is the best answer—delightfully succinct.

Comment: I think $node->get('field_destination')->entity also give the same result

Answer (score 9):

The following code will get you the term object you need.

```
$term = Term::load($node->get('field_destination')->target_id);
```

If you need the name of that term you can do the following

```
$name = $term->getName();
```

Hope this helps out!

Comment: How ever Term::load causing an issue.Fatal error: Class 'Drupal\rest\Plugin\Block\Term' not found .

Comment: @VJamie I tried adding `use \Drupal\taxonomy\Entity;` and used `Term::load($node->get('field_destination')->target_id);` but it failed. What class did you load?

Answer (score 2):

Do this

```
use Drupal\taxonomy\Entity\Term;
$term = Term::load($node->get('field_destination')->target_id);
$termname = $term->getName();
```

In drupal8 we used to follow oops approach to get the values.

Answer (score 1):

This is the correct way on how to achieve it

```
use Drupal\taxonomy\Entity\Term;

function modulename_node_presave(Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityInterface $entity) {
    switch ($entity->bundle()) {
        case 'programs':
            $term = Term::load($entity->get('field_program_names')->target_id);
            $name = $term->getName();
            $entity->setTitle($name);
            break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`entity` property can be accessed directly from any reference type field.

```
$node = 'myNode';
$termEntity = $node->get('field_taxonomy_reference')->entity;
if ($termEntity instanceof TermInterface) {
  $termLabel = $termEntity->label();
}
```