# Get Taxonomy Term ID by Node in Drupal 8

Tags: drupal-8

I'm trying to get Taxonomy data by particular node.

How can I get Taxonomy Term Id by using Node object ?

Drupal ver. 8.3.6

Comment: Possible duplicate of [drupal 8 get taxonomy term value in node](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37122908/drupal-8-get-taxonomy-term-value-in-node)

Comment: Probably no, the other answer belongs to previous version. The solution does not fit to current Drupal. (8.3.6 particularly)

Comment: what u have tried?update the code.

Answer (score 6):

You could do something like that:

```
$termId = $node->get('field_yourfield')->target_id;
```

Then you can load the term with

```
Term::load($termId);
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: You can also load the term from the node such as `node->get('field_yourfield')->entity` and from here retrieve the name such as `node->get('field_yourfield')->entity->name->value`.

Comment: `->target_id` is great if you just have a single term, unfortunately if, say, the user can tick multiple checkboxes, it only ever gives you the first one. I can't see anything obvious in the source code or with kint(), so back to ->referencedEntities() or getValue() it is…

Answer (score 5):

If you want to get Taxonomy Term data you can use this code:

```
$node->get('field_yourfield')->referencedEntities();
```

Hope it will be useful for you.

PS: If you need just Term's id you can use this:

```
$node->get('field_yourfield')->getValue();
```

You will get something like this:

```
[0 => ['target_id' => 23], 1 => ['target_id'] => 25]
```

In example my field has 2 referenced taxonomy terms. 
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

@Kevin Wenger's comment helped me.  I'm totally basing this answer on his comment.

In your code, when you have access to a fully loaded \Drupal\node\Entity\Node you can access all the (deeply) nested properties.

In this example, I've got a node which has a taxonomy term field "field_site". The "field_site" term itself has a plain text field "field_site_url_base".  In order to get the value of the "field_site_url_base", I can use the following:

```
$site_base_url = $node->get('field_site')->entity->field_site_url_base->value;
```

Answer (score 0):

How to extract **multiple** term IDs easily if you know a little **Laravel** (specifically [Collections](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/collections)):

Setup: `composer require tightenco/collect` to make Collections available in Drupal.

```
// see @Wau's answer for this first bit...
// remember: if you want the whole Term object, use ->referencedEntities()
$field_value = $node->get('field_yourfield')->getValue();

// then use collections to avoid loops etc.
$targets = collect($field_value)->pluck('target_id')->toArray();

// $targets = [1,2,3...]
```

or maybe you'd like the term IDs comma-separated? (I used this for programmatically passing contextual filter arguments to a view, which requires `,` (OR) or `+` (AND) to specify multiple values.)

```
$targets = collect($field_value)->implode('target_id', ',');

// $targets = "1,2,3"
```